# Error Message - Warning: require_once(__DIR__/android_connect/db_connect.php)

Tags: php, mysql, database

When I include database connect class inside the get_product.php its showing error message like

> require_once(**DIR**/android_connect/db_connect.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /home/a2667458/public_html/android_connect/get_products.php on line 12

in my file server `db_connect.php` path is 
`/public_html/android_connect/db_connect.php`

this is my code in `get_products.php`:

```
// include db connect class
require_once(__DIR__ .'/android_connect/db_connect.php');
// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
```

Comment: The error message is fairly self-explanatory: it cannot find the PHP file it needs. Look to see if there is a `android_connect` folder in the same folder as `get_products.php`, and if so, is there a file called `db_connect.php` inside it? Ensure the case of everything matches, too.

Comment: It may be worth checking the file permissions and user/group settings too. Do an `ls -l` in both folders and let us see what it says.

Comment: thank you for you comment its already solved, i call directly - require_once('/home/a2667458/public_html/android_connect/db_connect.php')

Comment: You're welcome. However, your solution is not ideal - if you need to move servers, and your virtual host directory changes, it will no longer work.

Comment: so can you explain the best way to do this please

Comment: I already have `:-)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

`require_once('/home/a2667458/public_html/android_connect/db_connect.php')`

or simply `require_once('db_connect.php')`.

`__DIR__` is the folder where the PHP file that contains it is located, so by saying:

`__DIR__ .'/android_connect/db_connect.php`

you are effectively saying:

`/home/a2667458/public_html/android_connect/android_connect/db_connect.php`

which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank You so much its working fine when i call directly - require_once('/home/a2667458/public_html/android_connect/db_connect.php')